SMPS schematic Review
I'm designing a homemade 12V 10A SMPS power supply. This is the third personal project that I'm doing before heading out to college (1st year btw). I created a schematic that's inspired by YouTuber LongTechnical's schematic.



Link to the original image source: Instructables - How to Build SMPS Transformer | Home Make 12V 10A Switching Power Supply by LongTechnical licensed under CC BY-NC-SA 4.0
(You'll have to scroll down to the comments to find his schematic.)

(My KiCad schematic.)
Before I go into the PCB editor and finish it, I want to know if my schematic looks pretty good for it to not blow up.

I'd take a closer look at that input choke. Is this powered direct from the mains?

@Finbarr - yeah, the input choke is direct from the mains.

Do a step load simulation 1st & include ESR, DCR, Lp, Ls etc

If you change anything in his assy, understand the consequences. Always consider detailed specs before any project. https://techweb.rohm.com/product/power-ic/acdc/812/#:~:text=Power%20supply%20specifications%20that%20must%20be%20fixed%201,%E3%83%BBRequired%20protection%3A%20Under-voltage%2C%20over-voltage%2C%20and%20over-heating%20More%20items

If you connect the common mode input choke this way, you will need many spare fuses and probably a torch light. If you want to provide 10 A at the output you need other chokes, the RN102-0.3-02-12M can only carry 300 mA, not even enough for the input side.

But it will blow up. See the input CM choke. Also you seem to have otherwise copied the circuit as-is but redrawn it in a way that is much harder to read than the original. Also we don't know why you made some changes like added R7. We also cannot see if these components are safe for mains use. If the purpose is to take parts from an old ATX supply to make a 12V 10A supply, why not simply use the ATX supply which is already safe and can provide more than 10A?

Also, using GND as the label where it is on both diagrams is misleading and dangerous - it carries a lethal voltage. It must not be connected to any sort of chassis or earth.


Before I go into the PCB editor and finish it, I want to know if my schematic looks pretty good for it to not blow up.

It looks nowhere close to being done. For one thing, since you are learning, you will need a variety of test points that can be accessed safely with a scope probe.
Ideally, those test points have to be all arranged along on edge of the PCB - that will face you while experimenting - so that you can easily attach probes to them.
For high voltage measurement beyond what a scope probe can accept, use resistive voltage divider.
For current measurements, use an IC current sensor with auxiliary supply, or a current transformer if the measurement is AC-only, or an op-amp-based current sensor.
To maintain a modicum of electrical safety, you will also need an isolation transformer for the mains side of it, and a variable autotransformer to safely ramp up the input voltage while monitoring the power consumption. See e.g. Thomas Scherrer's setup for safely powering up "unknown" electronic devices so that they don't just blow up.
Given the experimental nature of the supply, the entire thing should be approached as if it was energized from mains since you don't know enough to be sure which points are touch-safe and which are not.
Generally, I'd advise against doing this project without supervision of someone qualified. It's not only about it "not blowing up". If it doesn't blow up but doesn't work for whatever reason - how will you diagnose it safely, without hurting yourself or damaging components? It's not as trivial as just plugging it into mains and keeping your fingers crossed.
And if it does "blow up" and you take a shard of a transistor or an IC or a diode on your face, how will you feel then? It's not a hypothetical. It happened to me when working on an SMPS - and that SMPS was nominally working fine. Until it was not. There was a sheet of clear polycarbonate between my face and the supply, otherwise I'd have a permanent scar.
